# moving div according to mouse event and in the same direction

Tags: javascript, jquery

im trying to move the div according to mouse event and direction, i mean to move the div in the same direction, in which moves the mouse, but for the movement of div there will be limits. so far i have this:

```
    $("#foo").mousemove(function(event) {
        $("#bee1").animate({"left": "150px"}, 2000)
    });
```

and css:

```
#bee1 { position:absolute; top:200px; left:160px; }
```

now the div moves just in one direction, after the mouse is moved, and stops. but i want it to be moved in the way moves mouse, in the same direction )) how do i do it?!
Thank you all for help!

Comment: Have you considered using http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/ ?

Comment: no, i dont want to drag it, i want to move it accoring to mouse movements, and in the same direction, but with limited range, no mouse clicks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for this

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vhDpG/)**

```
$("#foo").mousemove(function(event) {
        $("#bee1").stop().animate({left: event.pageX, top: event.pageY}, 300)
});
```

Comment: thats more like it :) thank you! but how do i put the limits?!

Comment: The limits is set by `foo`'s dimensions which I have set in the css in my demo take a look.

Comment: now i got it )) very good and easy way to do exactly what i wanted! thank very much again!

Comment: oops :) one little problem, there are actually limits, but i want it to move after the mouse even if the mouse is outside the foo div

Comment: Then attach mouse move event on the `document` object.

Comment: look, how do i attach it from here? http://jsfiddle.net/vhDpG/2/ sorry, im a newbie in this jquery...

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.thinqlinq.com/Post.aspx/Title/Select-Many-with-Rx-and-RxJs for an example using RxJs.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract `event.pageX` and `event.pageY` every time `mousemove` is triggered. By storing these as global variables and comparing them to subsequent values, you can compute exactly what direction the mouse has been moved in and how far.

http://api.jquery.com/event.pageX/

Take the difference between the new and old values and feed them back directly into `.animate` if you like.

Comment: ok, thanks, thats what i want, but in theory, can you show me the example of it?!